# Tabulating list of values in third variable in R

Tags: r

I have following data:

```
ddf2 = structure(list(col1 = c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3), col2 = c("c", "c", "b", 
"b", "b", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b", "c", "c", "b", "b", "a", "c", 
"c", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a", "c", "a"), col3 = c("C", "E", 
"E", "B", "D", "E", "C", "C", "E", "E", "C", "A", "D", "D", "C", 
"E", "A", "A", "A", "D", "A", "A", "B", "A", "E")), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")

head(ddf2)
  col1 col2 col3
1    3    c    C
2    3    c    E
3    2    b    E
4    1    b    B
5    1    b    D
6    1    a    E
```

For every combination of col1 and col2, there may be many values of col3:

```
with(ddf2, ddf2[col1==1 & col2=='b',])
   col1 col2 col3
4     1    b    B
5     1    b    D
9     1    b    E
10    1    b    E
13    1    b    D
20    1    b    D
21    1    b    A


with(ddf2, table(col1, col2))
    col2
col1 a b c
   1 2 7 3
   2 1 3 1
   3 2 1 5
```

I want to create a table/matrix of col1 and col2 as above but each cell should have a list of unique col3 entries for that set of col1 and col2. I expect following output:

```
    col2
col1    a       b           c
1       E,C     A,B,D,E     A,E
2       B       A,D,E       C
3       A,E     C           A,C,E
```

I tried following but it does not work:

```
with(ddf2, tapply(col3, list(col1,col2), c))
  a           b           c          
1 Character,2 Character,7 Character,3
2 "B"         Character,3 "C"        
3 Character,2 "C"         Character,5
```

How can this be done? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
d <- with(ddf2, aggregate(col3 ~ col2 + col1, FUN = function(x) paste0(unique(x))))
library(reshape2)
dcast(d, col1 ~ col2, value.var = "col3")
#  col1    a          b       c
#1    1 E, C B, D, E, A    A, E
#2    2    B    E, D, A       C
#3    3 A, E          C C, E, A
```

Most likely it's possible to do both steps in one, but I'll generously leave it to someone else to figure this out ;)

Or

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ddf2 %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  summarise(col3 = paste(unique(col3), collapse = ", ")) %>%
  spread(col2, col3)

#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#
#  col1    a          b       c
#1    1 E, C B, D, E, A    A, E
#2    2    B    E, D, A       C
#3    3 A, E          C C, E, A
```

Edit after comment:

Just tested with `tapply` and this seems to work (the problem was apparently in calling `c()`):

```
with(ddf2, tapply(col3, list(col1,col2), FUN = function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ", ")))
#  a      b            c        
#1 "E, C" "B, D, E, A" "A, E"   
#2 "B"    "E, D, A"    "C"      
#3 "A, E" "C"          "C, E, A"
```

Comment: I was about to post this slightly different answer, which is based on the same principle:
    library(plyr)
    test=ddply(ddf2,c("col1","col2"),summarise, unique=paste(unique(col3),collapse=","))
    dcast(test,col1~col2,value.var="unique")

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why tapply does not work here: with(ddf2, tapply(col3, list(col2,col1), FUN = function(x) paste0(unique(x)))) ; it gives entries like: Character,2 etc.

Comment: @rnso, I added an example with `tapply`.

Comment: @beginneR: Great. I was trying 'c' function. Any way that can work?

Comment: Run `d <- with(ddf2, tapply(col3, list(col1,col2), FUN = function(x) c(x)))` and then check `str(d)`. you'll notice that the information you need is actually in there, but can't be displayed or somehow doesn't fit the normal data.frame structure (I know this description is probably not accurate but I don't know how else to describe it). basically, I think the problem is `c()` returns a vector but you can't display a vector in a single "cell" of a data.frame. That's why you should use `paste` instead.